# How to render a template with VueJS and Axios?

Tags: api, flask, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have a Vue app that generates as many forms as the user likes. Each form represent a `'risk'` in this `'risks'` data model:

```
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        risks: [
          {
            'risk_name': '', 'fields': [{'field': '', 'type': ''}], 'errors':[]
          }
        ],
      },
```

Then I send the `'risks'` to a *post* API request. Then I make a second *get* request that brings back a template with the processed data as JSON. So far so good. However, how do I render the template (new page) with this data.

This is how I receive the data:

```
    Submit() {
       if (this.checkValidity()) {
        console.info(this.risks)
        axios.post('risks', this.risks)

        .then(function(response) {
          axios.get('risks')//This gets the data back
        })

        .catch(function(error) {
          alert('This Error occured: ' + error)
        })

      }
    },
```

This is the `GET` API call that I called above (Flask):

```
@app.route('/risks', methods=['GET'])
def getInsurancePolicyForm():
    risks = getTables(app.metadata)
    return render_template('form.html', risks=risks)
```

I can see the rendered template in developer tools, but the page the user sees remains the same.

Comment: Your page should be built using the `risks` array in data, that way when the user adds a new risk, Vue will auto render the page as is. Why do you need to get the template back from the API call?

Comment: In the first page the user specifies risk names, risk fields and data types (text, number...etc) then in the second page the user should see a form based on these specs to fill the risks. So, for text datatype he’ll see a text field ... etc. @webnoob

Comment: @webnoob I added a screen shot of the risks form.

Comment: My point still stands, build all that information into the `risks` array, loop through that array and show the data based on the fields they've selected etc.

Comment: I've knocked up an example of what I mean for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page should be focussed on the `risks` object instead of the response from the API call.

When the user selects options, add them to the risks data object so your risks object looks like:

```
risks: [
  {
    'risk_name': '', 'fields': [{'field': 'My Field', 'type': 'text', modelToHoldData: ''}], 'errors':[]
  }
]
```

Then, when the user clicks on Submit, by all means send it to the API but you don't need a template from there, use the `risks` object like so (remembering to hide the form they've just chosen their fields with):

```
<div v-for="risk in risks">
    <label>{{risk.field}}</label>
    <input type="text" v-if="risk.type === 'text'" v-model="risk.modelToHoldData" />
</div>
```

You can adjust the above example to add as many variations of the example as you allow the user to select.

Once all this is done and you need access to the data the user enters, you can loop through the array again and just access the `modelToHoldData` prop on each of the `risks`.